# ApacheDS - default service fails to start on Windows

Tags: windows, ldap, apacheds, openjdk-17

I have been trying to start ApacheDS service on windows for a while, but failed.
I want to connect to [LDAP](https://searchmobilecomputing.techtarget.com/definition/LDAP) but the [ApacheDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Directory) service can't start.

I tried to check my wrapper log file and found the error -

**Unable to load the Wrapper's native library 'wrapper.dll'**.

However, I am running a 64-bits JVM and my computer has 64-bits as well. How can I find the wrapper.dll file of 64-bits, if it is the cause to the error?

I hope if this error gets fixed, I will be able to connect LDAP without error: **[LDAP result code 52 - unavailable] Proxy operation retry failed**.

Thank you for your assistance.

[wrapper log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El9ML.png)

Comment: Encountered the same problem, following.

Comment: I am using "ApacheDirectoryStudio-2.0.0.v20210717-M17-win32.win32.x86_64" with "OpenJDK11U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_11.0.12_7" now I am able to start directory server from directory studio. Note: I am using embedded directory server in directory studio and I am on Windows 11.

Comment: Is it necessary to start Apache DS as a service for you. Any reason you cant change to apace ds bin directory and execute apacheds.bat?